# How can I adapt my code to add a count to provide feedback on where the script is in regards to completion?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

How can I adapt my code below to provide feedback on where in the script it is? I would like to have something like `print(f"Processed {count} / {len(items)}")`.

```
pool = mp.Pool(10)
manager = mp.Manager()
return_dict = manager.dict()
res = pool.map(first_parse, iterable=items)
pool.close()
pool.join()
data_list = list(zip(items, res))
```

Comment: Use print statements???

Comment: @itprorh66 funny

Answer (score 0):

You could use `imap` (iterator version of `map`) and print status yourself.  `enumerate` is useful to count the results as they are returned.  Below is designed to run at a terminal with `\r` (carriage return without linefeed) support. An f-string is used to format a "percent done" value that updates on the same line.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def process(data):
    time.sleep(.01)
    return data * 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        for i,res in enumerate(pool.imap(process,range(1000)),start=1):
            print(f'\r{i/1000:6.1%}',end='',flush=True)
```

But check out [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) for more sophisticated methods.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Mark Tolonen was on the right track but misses one key point: Both `map` and `imap` return results in the order in which tasks are submitted, not in the order in which they are completed. In the worse case scenario, imagine that the job submitted that is for the first item in the *iterable* argument passed to `imap` is the last one to complete and you were using `tqdm` as a visual method of displaying where you were in the completion of the tasks. The `tqdm` bar would be pegged at 0 until the first task completed. But that would only occur after all the other tasks submitted had completed. So you would see nothing happen for a while and then all of a sudden the bar would shoot to 100% in a flash.

To get an *accurate* picture of the completion progress, your best bet is to use `apply_async` with a callback function (using `imap_unordered` with the default *chunksize* argument of 1 *seems* to return the results in task completion order, but the documentation does not guarantee that). This may mean that your worker function might need to be modified to return the original argument passed to it so that you can tie the result back to the argument used to create the result.

Now I do not see in your code where `return_dict` is being passed to your worker function, `first_pass`. If it is meant to be, and that is where the worker function is storing its results, then presumably the order in which the results are returned is inconsequential. On the other hand I see that you are explcitly using the return list from `map` and zipping it up with `items`, which suggests the order does matter, which I will assume. So I will be passing to `first_pass` the index of the result list that the result it passes back should stored at.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp

def first_parse(idx, item):
    import time
    import random

    time.sleep(random.random() * 5)
    ... # calculate result
    return idx, item ** 2 # return original idx


def my_callback(t):
    global completed
    idx, result = t
    res[idx] = result
    completed += 1
    print(f"Processed {completed * 100 / result_size}%")

# required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(10)
    #manager = mp.Manager()
    # sample items:
    items = range(10)
    result_size = len(items)
    # preallocate the res list:
    res = [None] * result_size
    # pass enumerate so that the result index is passed and can be returned back:
    # Now first_pass argument will be a tuple:
    completed = 0
    for idx, item in enumerate(items):
        pool.apply_async(first_parse, args=(idx, item), callback=my_callback)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    data_list = list(zip(items, res))
    print(data_list)
```

Prints:

```
Processed 10.0%
Processed 20.0%
Processed 30.0%
Processed 40.0%
Processed 50.0%
Processed 60.0%
Processed 70.0%
Processed 80.0%
Processed 90.0%
Processed 100.0%
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16), (5, 25), (6, 36), (7, 49), (8, 64), (9, 81)]
```